# How to find the unused dependencies in an Android Project?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

My app size is too large, I want to find unused dependencies and then remove them. Can someone help me with that?
I did try the nebula/gradle-lint, but had no luck with that.

Comment: Are you testing the size of the debug or release apk? In theory, in release builds you'll have Proguard/R8 which most likely remove any unused dependencies or optimize the code.

Comment: @lulian I am looking at the release version. It's around 100 mb.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer and realize that [Google Play will require Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) which will handle multi-apk support.

Comment: Then maybe check that `minifyEnabled` is set (otherwise it won't runt the optimizer). And if it's set or the apk is still to large, then analyze your apk as @MorrisonChang said. From there, you'll find what's causing this problem (source code, resources, assets, etc.)